# User Restrictions based on Field Content in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, user-interface, user-input, restrictions

I need to set up user permissions within the same table, based on the value of a field. I know that this is not directly possible in Access but a post on Allenbrown.com points to a way of doing this [see here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-55.html). I'm not proficient in coding so I'm hoping that I can get some directions from you. Here are the details:

I have two tables in the database, a parent one populated via a form and a children one populated via a subform. The parent contains companies and the child contain subsidiaries of those companies. In the child table, I have a field called "Domicile" and I want to discriminate user access based on that. Because the database will be used by a variety of people worldwide, my plan is to create user groups based on location and allow users to edit (or add) information based on a match between their location (as specified in the group) and the domicile of the subsidiary. For example, a person in Europe will only be allowed to edit data for subsidiaries that are in Europe, even though companies from other domiciles may be stored in the same table.

I'm looking for some guidance here as well as suggestions as to how you think may be done most effectively. I'm not partial to this method, that's just something I came up with to put some logic behind what I'm doing.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing to note in Allen's description is (emphasis mine):

> **Assuming all updates are performed through forms**, the Current event of the form then locks the fields based on this property.

There would be no practical, bulletproof way to prevent users from viewing and altering *any* data in the table(s) if they open the back-end database file directly.

Since you are asking for advice on how *"[row- or column-level restrictions] may be done most effectively"* the first issue you need to address is how "effective" those restrictions really need to be:

1. If you can accept that these will be "soft restrictions" (really a matter of convenience to the user so they don't accidentally alter certain records or fields while using the forms), then Allen's approach might be sufficient. (If so, then follow Allen's instructions as best you can and [ask new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you need help with a specific aspect of that implementation.)
2. On the other hand, if you need "hard restrictions" (serious protection against mischievous or malevolent user activity) then you'll have to employ a different database back-end -- something like Microsoft SQL Server -- with a richer set of security tools for you to use.

Comment: Thank you so much Gord. Yes, I am aware of the limitations but I plan to add table based controls to further enhance security, although the DB will be used by members of my team, I tend not to be as paranoid as the big bosses on malevolent/intentional data alteration, plus let's face it. I'm pretty good at Excel and I'm going nuts on Access, people will not bother. Once you enter Access, you're in a minefield :)

Comment: I posted the new question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917839/field-restrictions-based-on-user-group-allen-method-tweak)